# how to replace specific characters in a data frame by the value in a variable in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe looks like:

```
df <- read.table(text="chr     pos Ref Alt D045313 D045314 D045135 D045136 D045137 D045138
Chr1 1462191   T   C     1/1     0/1     1/1     0/0     1/1     1/1
Chr1 1463534   G   C     0/0     1/1     0/0     0/1     0/0     0/0
Chr1 1463881   T   A     0/1     0/0     1/1     0/0     1/1     1/1
Chr1 1464091   G   A     0/0     0/0     1/1     0/0     1/1     1/1
Chr1 1464651   T   C     1/1     0/0     1/1     0/1    1/1     1/1",head=F, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

The expected result:

```
  chr     pos Ref Alt D045313 D045314 D045135 D045136 D045137 D045138
Chr1 1462191   T   C     C/C     T/C     C/C     T/T     C/C     C/C
Chr1 1463534   G   C     G/G     C/C     G/G     G/C     G/G     G/G
Chr1 1463881   T   A     T/A     T/T     A/A     T/T     A/A     A/A
Chr1 1464091   G   A     G/G     G/G     A/A     G/G     A/A     A/A
Chr1 1464651   T   C     C/C     T/T     C/C     T/C    C/C     C/C
```

the replacements would follow this:
in **df[5:10]**, "0" should be replaced by the character in **df$Ref**, "1" by the character in **df$Alt**. I checked the question in this link[[Replace specific characters in a variable in data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470307/replace-specific-characters-in-a-variable-in-data-frame-in-r][1]), but it didn't work on my situation. Appreciate any helps.

Comment: This question is the reverse operation of question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358776/how-to-replace-elements-of-text-by-a-condition-in-r)

Comment: It's okay. I find some similarities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating data:

```
df <- read.table(text="chr     pos Ref Alt D045313 D045314 D045135 D045136 D045137 D045138
                 Chr1 1462191   T   C     1/1     0/1     1/1     0/0     1/1     1/1
                 Chr1 1463534   G   C     0/0     1/1     0/0     0/1     0/0     0/0
                 Chr1 1463881   T   A     0/1     0/0     1/1     0/0     1/1     1/1
                 Chr1 1464091   G   A     0/0     0/0     1/1     0/0     1/1     1/1
                 Chr1 1464651   T   C     1/1     0/0     1/1     0/1    1/1     1/1",head=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Using `gsub`:

```
vgsub<- Vectorize(gsub, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
new <- vgsub("0", df$Ref, as.data.frame(t(df[5:10])))
new <- vgsub("1", df$Alt, new)
df[5:10] <- do.call("rbind", new)
df
  chr     pos Ref Alt D045313 D045314 D045135 D045136 D045137 D045138
1 Chr1 1462191   T   C     C/C     T/C     C/C     T/T     C/C     C/C
2 Chr1 1463534   G   C     G/G     C/C     G/G     G/C     G/G     G/G
3 Chr1 1463881   T   A     T/A     T/T     A/A     T/T     A/A     A/A
4 Chr1 1464091   G   A     G/G     G/G     A/A     G/G     A/A     A/A
5 Chr1 1464651   T   C     C/C     T/T     C/C     T/C     C/C     C/C
```

Comment: Simple and fast. only 15.61 sec on my real data

Answer (score 4):

Using `data.table`

```
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) gsub("0", Ref, gsub("1", Alt, x))), 
            by = .(chr, pos)]

#    chr     pos Ref Alt D045313 D045314 D045135 D045136 D045137 D045138
#1: Chr1 1462191   T   C     C/C     T/C     C/C     T/T     C/C     C/C
#2: Chr1 1463534   G   C     G/G     C/C     G/G     G/C     G/G     G/G
#3: Chr1 1463881   T   A     T/A     T/T     A/A     T/T     A/A     A/A
#4: Chr1 1464091   G   A     G/G     G/G     A/A     G/G     A/A     A/A
#5: Chr1 1464651   T   C     C/C     T/T     C/C     T/C     C/C     C/C
```

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate_each(funs(gsub("0", Ref, gsub("1", Alt, .))), matches("^D04."))

#   chr     pos Ref Alt D045313 D045314 D045135 D045136 D045137 D045138
#1 Chr1 1462191   T   C     C/C     T/C     C/C     T/T     C/C     C/C
#2 Chr1 1463534   G   C     G/G     C/C     G/G     G/C     G/G     G/G
#3 Chr1 1463881   T   A     T/A     T/T     A/A     T/T     A/A     A/A
#4 Chr1 1464091   G   A     G/G     G/G     A/A     G/G     A/A     A/A
#5 Chr1 1464651   T   C     C/C     T/T     C/C     T/C     C/C     C/C
```

Another option

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
   gather(key, value, -c(chr, pos, Ref, Alt)) %>% rowwise %>% 
   mutate(value = gsub("0", Ref, gsub("1", Alt, value))) %>%    
   spread(key, value)

#Source: local data frame [5 x 10]

#   chr     pos Ref Alt D045313 D045314 D045135 D045136 D045137 D045138
#1 Chr1 1462191   T   C     C/C     T/C     C/C     T/T     C/C     C/C
#2 Chr1 1463534   G   C     G/G     C/C     G/G     G/C     G/G     G/G
#3 Chr1 1463881   T   A     T/A     T/T     A/A     T/T     A/A     A/A
#4 Chr1 1464091   G   A     G/G     G/G     A/A     G/G     A/A     A/A
#5 Chr1 1464651   T   C     C/C     T/T     C/C     T/C     C/C     C/C
```

**base R option** using `apply`

```
data.frame(t(
  apply(df, 1, 
  function(x) c(x[c(1:4)], gsub("0", x['Ref'], gsub("1", x['Alt'], x[c(5:10)]))))
 ))

#   chr     pos Ref Alt D045313 D045314 D045135 D045136 D045137 D045138
#1 Chr1 1462191   T   C     C/C     T/C     C/C     T/T     C/C     C/C
#2 Chr1 1463534   G   C     G/G     C/C     G/G     G/C     G/G     G/G
#3 Chr1 1463881   T   A     T/A     T/T     A/A     T/T     A/A     A/A
#4 Chr1 1464091   G   A     G/G     G/G     A/A     G/G     A/A     A/A
#5 Chr1 1464651   T   C     C/C     T/T     C/C     T/C     C/C     C/C
```

Comment: data.table solution used 143.22 sec. dplyr used 488.27 sec. others are in testing

Comment: The third solution run 547.4 sec. and last one used 16.83 sec.

Comment: It is interesting that the `apply` solution is very fast.  Probably for rowwise, apply would be better here.

Comment: @akrun yes, I am wondering why dt approach is comparatively very slow!

Comment: I think for rowwise operations, `data.table` won't be adding much value as you are grouping by two variables to make it rowwise

Comment: .SDcols is for selecting the columns.  Here you want to apply it through the rows.  So, I guess this is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that you can use to fill in the values in this case and be able to change for future cases too.

```
convert_val <- function(df) {
  reference_cols <- c("chr", "pos", "Ref", "Alt")
  morph <- function(DF,vec,First="0", Second="1") {
  m <- mapply(function(x,y) gsub(First, x,y), x=DF[,"Ref"], y=DF[,vec])
  mapply(function(x,y) gsub(Second, x,y), x=DF[,"Alt"], y=m)
}
  nums <- which(!names(df) %in% reference_cols)
  df[, nums] <- lapply(nums,function(x) morph(df,x))
  df
}

convert_val(df)
#    chr     pos Ref Alt D045313 D045314 D045135 D045136 D045137 D045138
# 1 Chr1 1462191   T   C     C/C     T/C     C/C     T/T     C/C     C/C
# 2 Chr1 1463534   G   C     G/G     C/C     G/G     G/C     G/G     G/G
# 3 Chr1 1463881   T   A     T/A     T/T     A/A     T/T     A/A     A/A
# 4 Chr1 1464091   G   A     G/G     G/G     A/A     G/G     A/A     A/A
# 5 Chr1 1464651   T   C     C/C     T/T     C/C     T/C     C/C     C/C
```

In the future, you can change the `First` and `Second` arguments for the internal function `morph` to whatever the new values to look for are (default is `"0"` and `"1"`). Or if your column names change, you can adjust the line `reference_cols`.